# Authentication with POST request is failing to validate data

Tags: swift

So I have a created a POST request which validates the Username and Password when someone tries to login, The problem is when i press the button sender it doesn't validate the data at all even if the Username and Password field are empty it still segues you to the main Dashboard which I find it very weird.

The Button Sender from `signInViewController` class :

```
@IBAction func signInSegueToDashboard(_ sender: Any) {
    
    APICallerPOST.shared.signInToAccount(username: emailFieldSignIn.text!, password: passwordFieldSignIn.text!) { [self] (result, error) in
        
        switch result?.StatusCode {
        case 0:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                activityLoaderSignIn.startAnimating()
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                
                guard let mainTabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainTabBarController")
                else {
                    return
                }
                
                self.activityLoaderSignIn.stopAnimating()
                mainTabBarController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
                self.present(mainTabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        case 1:
            print("error")
        case 2:
            print("error2")
        case 3:
            print("error3")
        case 4:
            print("error4")
        case 5:
            print("error5")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that even if the `emailFieldSignIn.text!` and `passwordFieldSignIn.text!` are empty it still segues you to the mainTabBarController without any validation of the data.

The POST request from `APICallerPOST` class :

```
func signInToAccount(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (SignInResponse?, Error?) -> Void) {
    
    //declare parameter as a dictionary which contains string as key and value combination.
    let parameters = ["User": username, "Password": password]
    
    //create the url with NSURL
    let url = URL(string: "https://censoredurl/Signin")!
    
    //create the session object
    let session = URLSession.shared
    
    //now create the Request object using the url object
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST
    
    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to data object and set it as request body
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        completion(nil, error)
    }
    
    //HTTP Headers
    request.addValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    
    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        
        guard error == nil else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
            completion(nil, NSError(domain: "dataNilError", code: -100001, userInfo: nil))
            return
        }
        
        do {
            //create json object from data
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    
            guard let json = try? decoder.decode(SignInResponse.self, from: data) else {
               completion(nil, NSError(domain: "invalidJSONTypeError", code: -100009, userInfo: nil))
               return
            }
            
            print(json)
            completion(json, nil)
            
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    })
    
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: I can't see your validation. Where are you validating your UITextfields.

Comment: @HammerClass good question, well I am new here so i thought that it all depends on StatusCode, Can you reference a code to see of UITextFields validations please Hammer? , And you are right all the point is at validating the UITextFields if they are empty to throw error etc.

Comment: It's unclear. There is no segue in your code. There is a modal presentation, not a segue. Also, don't use `print(error.localizedDescription)`, but `print(error)`, and don' you have a do/catch warning because you are not using `try`, but `try?` (meaning: try but ignore the error if there is one thrown)?

Comment: @Larme hey stack overflows angel, The problem was that I wasn't validating the UITextFields and the response code was still 0 even if they were empty so I know added a code to validate if they are empty to throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my answer it will be helpfull for you I have added compulsory checks to validate if UITextfields are empty or not you can also add valid email check.

```
  @IBAction func signInSegueToDashboard(_ sender: Any) {
                if emailFieldSignIn.text!.isEmpty || passwordFieldSignIn.text!.isEmpty{
    //                show some error
                     return
                 }
                APICallerPOST.shared.signInToAccount(username: emailFieldSignIn.text!, password: passwordFieldSignIn.text!) { [self] (result, error) in
                    
                    switch result?.StatusCode {
                    case 0:
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            
                            activityLoaderSignIn.startAnimating()
                        }
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                            
                            guard let mainTabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainTabBarController")
                            else {
                                return
                            }
                            
                            self.activityLoaderSignIn.stopAnimating()
                            mainTabBarController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
                            self.present(mainTabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    case 1:
                        print("error")
                    case 2:
                        print("error2")
                    case 3:
                        print("error3")
                    case 4:
                        print("error4")
                    case 5:
                        print("error5")
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Exactly what i was needing my man, Because I saw that even if the text fields was empty the StatusCode was coming 0 which shouldn't have came 0 since its only when user is valid but anyways Thanks a lot!